# Is it ok to append the nonce/iv to the ciphertext when using AES GCM?

Tags: aes, nonce

I want to use AES GCM to encrypt data at rest. When retrieving the data, I want to make sure that the key is valid and the data has not been tempered with. Can I store the nonce/iv along with the ciphertext in the database?

Comment: i thought GCM was authenticated anyway; if you can decrypt it, it hasn't been tampered with...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely. There is no risk from appending the nounce/iv to encrypted text.

Comment: > There is **know** risk from appending the nounce/iv to encrypted text.

Did you mean there is **no** risk?

Comment: sorry. Yep I mean NO risk.

Comment: @machete It's funny that you pointed out a spelling error when you wrote "tempered" instead of "tampered"!

Comment: @cj-dennis what is really funny is you picking on a two year old question with a senseless comment like that. There is a huge difference between „no“ and „known“ security vulnerability (in case you didn’t notice). Obviously it’s important to sort that out, which happened. Thank you for your contribution though...

Comment: @machete It doesn't matter how old the question is. I had the same question today, which is how I found yours. Two other people have already found your question useful and who knows how many people might visit this question in the future. If I don't know what "nonce" means, I might think that there is a technical term called "tempering the data". It's best to be clear, as you discovered yourself. ;-)

Comment: And how about the `tag`?